# Extending expect-webdriverio with custom matchers

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

I need to make a custom matcher for my wdio typescript framework. I looked at https://github.com/webdriverio/expect-webdriverio/blob/master/docs/Extend.md and done everything, i copied and pasted exactly the same code. So in my before() hook:

```
const matchers = require('myMatchers');
matchers.addCustomMatchers();
```

And right next to my wdio conf file:

```
module.exports = {
    addCustomMatchers: () => {
        console.log("MY MATCHER");
        expect.extend({
            myMatcher(actual, expected) {
                return { pass: actual === expected, message: () => 'some message' }
            },
        })
    }
}
```

When i start tests, i see "MY MATCHER" line in console. So it gets executed properly.
But i cant see myMatcher when trying to do expect. What i missed?

Comment: "cant see myMatcher". 

Not sure what does it mean. You can't see it where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc is valid. For TypeScript project, you have to declare types as well.

See my example project:

1. [before hook](https://github.com/mgrybyk/webdriverio-devtools/blob/144bf99b2f33c17a219ad348f50d911ef97a57e6/config/wdio.conf.ts#L31)
2. [matchers](https://github.com/mgrybyk/webdriverio-devtools/blob/master/src/matchers.ts)
3. [matcher types](https://github.com/mgrybyk/webdriverio-devtools/blob/master/src/%40types/wdio-expect.d.ts)
4. [usage in test](https://github.com/mgrybyk/webdriverio-devtools/blob/144bf99b2f33c17a219ad348f50d911ef97a57e6/test/specs/navigation.spec.ts#L32)

Note:
Make sure to you the latest wdio packages and a valid tsconfig.json. You can find all that in the project.

Comment: Thank you really much, your example worked great for me!

Comment: Using WebDriverIO v8.14.x, I had to add the require in the `beforeFeature` hook instead of the `before` hook.